# Simple test if Ros was installed correctly?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

warning I am a newbie. I followed the instructions on the ros website for installation on ubuntu. I believe everything worked but I was wondering if there is a command or easy tutorial to check if I installed everything correctly.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33812/simple-test-if-ros-was-installed-correctly?/) by [mlandergan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2136/mlandergan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlandergan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2136/mlandergan/) on 2012-05-12**:
Great, everything is working thank you for the help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try typing

```
rosversion ros
```

in a terminal. If it gives you a version number, ROS is installed. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-12**:
@Ryan ;-)

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-12**:
I was going to suggest running 'roscore', and seeing what happened. Same result.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-12**:
@Mac Yeah ! good alternative, even rospack find  would do the job.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-01-20**:
`rosversion` ros yields  `<unversioned>` for me. What does it mean?

**Comment by [wall_e](https://answers.ros.org/users/23349/wall_e/) on 2015-07-27**:
For rosversion I get : Cannot locate.
roscore: command not found.

What should i do?

**Comment by [alexandergmzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/88103/alexandergmzx/) on 2021-10-26**:
This does not work for new ROS versions, try using just

```
rosversion -d
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosversion -d for indigo

---

Originally posted by [adarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25866/adarsh/) with karma: 21 on 2016-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2020-07-10**:
`rosversion -d` should work for all of ROS distribution, including kinetic, indigo etc.

**Comment by [alexandergmzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/88103/alexandergmzx/) on 2021-10-26**:
This also works for ROS2 foxy :)

```
rosversion -d
```

and you have it, welcome to ROS community.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosversion roscpp
```

worked for me.

```
rosversion ros
```

returned

```
<unversioned>
```

---

Originally posted by [aidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/26971/aidos/) with karma: 41 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaustubh Patil](https://answers.ros.org/users/51893/kaustubh-patil/) on 2020-02-20**:
Same for me
Then why did rosversion ros didnt worked